# sed - insert line after X lines after match

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have the following contents:

```
void function_1()
{
    //something (taking only 1 line)
}
->INSERT LINE HERE<-
//more code
```

Using sed, I want to insert line at the INSERT LINE HERE label.
The easiest way should be:

1. find text "function_1"
2. skip 3 lines
3. insert new line

But none of the known sed options do the job.

```
sed '/function_1/,3a new_text
```

inserts new_text right after 'function_1'

```
sed '/function_1/,+3a new_text
```

inserts new_text after each of the next 3 lines, following 'function_1'

```
sed '/function_1/N;N;N; a new_text
```

inserts new_text at multiple places, not related to the pattern

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed "/function_1/{N;N;N;a new_text
}" filename
```

Comment: Alternatively: `sed '/function_1/!{p;d;};n;n;n;a new text'` It's more roundabout but works without a newline in the sed code (because the `a` command is at the end).

Comment: I guess that this approach doesn't work on all versions of sed, as POSIX specifies that you should use `a\ ` followed by a newline in order to append text.

Comment: @TomFenech: I added "GNU sed". Thank you.

Comment: I like this solution but i want some `tab` in my `next text`

Answer (score 4):

Use awk:

```
awk '1;/function_1/{c=4}c&&!--c{print "new text"}' file
```

- `1` is a shorthand for `{print}`, so all lines in the file are printed
- when the pattern is matched, set `c` to 4
- when `c` reaches 1 (so `c` is true and `!--c` is true), insert the line

You could just use `!--c` but adding the check for `c` being true as well means that `c` doesn't keep decreasing beyond 0.

Comment: This is freaking awesome and same time complex but i like this approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/function_1(/,/^[[:space:]]*}/ {
 ,/^[[:space:]]*}/ a\
Line that\
you want to\
insert (append) here
   }' YourFile
```

- insert the line after the `}` (alone in the line with eventually some space before) from the section starting with `function_1(`
- i assume there is no `}` alone in your internal code like in your sample

be carreful on selection based on function name because it could be used  (and normaly it is) as a call to the function itself in other code section so maybe a `/^void function_1()$/` is better

Answer (score 1):

Don't count, match:

```
sed -e '/^void function_1()/,/^}$/ { /^}$/a\
TEXT TO INSERT
}' input
```

This looks at the block between the declaration and the closing brace, and then append TEXT_TO_INSERT after the closing brace.