# sed : Insert line after n lines following the pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Pls bear with me as I knew this questions has been asked a few time by others, yet I keep getting error with the suggested answers.

Original file:

```
    a1
    a2
    a3

product 2 
    b1
    b2
    b3

product 3
    c1
    c2
    c3
```

I would like to add string '1111111' two lines after match pattern 'product', fetch to a file 'out'. Such like:

```
product 1 
    a1
    a2
    1111111
    a3
product 2 
    b1
    b2
    1111111
    b3

product 3
    c1
    c2
    1111111
    c3
```

Those links I referred are suggesting the command as below but I get an error:

```
sed '/product/{n;n;a \    1111111'} file > out


sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

I would like to achieve this using sed?

These are links I'm refering:
[Insert line after match using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559359/insert-line-after-match-using-sed)
[sed - insert line after X lines after match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099736/sed-insert-line-after-x-lines-after-match)

Thank you.

Comment: `sed -e '/^product/{n;n;a1111111' -e '}' file`

Comment: *would like to achieve this using sed* then please explain why have you use `awk` tag

Comment: Thank you Hatless. Your suggestion works for me. Would you mind explain why I need two separated -e switched here? Also, wonder why some other sed command I don't need -e at all?

Comment: Hi Hatless, I changed the code a bit  so that it only fetch string to certain product. However I get error: Unmatched ".

Comment: Here is my code. May I know where goes wrong? foreach product (`cat product_list.txt`)
sed -e "/(${product}/{n;n;n;n;n;a \    product_type : \"Industrial Goods\" ; ' -e '}" file > out
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either adding the -e option as Hatless suggested, or add one linebreak after your `a` command:

```
$ sed '/product/{n;n;a\    1111111 
}' f                                   
product 1 
    a1
    a2
    1111111
    a3

product 2 
    b1
    b2
    1111111
    b3

product 3
    c1
    c2
    1111111
    c3
```

Comment: Thanks you Kent. Same as what Hatless suggested, this works for me, however  I don't understand why need a break before the closing braces.